# Objective-c TableView real time refresh custom cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

Hello I have tableview with custom cell and I want to do realtime refresh my codes under.

```
       @interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

        @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *jsonArray;
        @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array1;
        @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *entryDict;

        @end


        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];

         _tableView.delegate = self;
            [self refresh];
        }

        - (void)refresh
        {
            NSString *urlduzenli = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bla.com/server/table.php?OrderId=%@",suankioturumid];
            NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlduzenli];

            NSURLRequest * urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            NSError * error;

            NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlReq returningResponse:nil error:&error];

            if (!error) {
                NSDictionary * jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

                _jsonArray = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"orders"];

                _array1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            }else{

            }
   [self.tableView reloadData];
            }

        -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

            return _jsonArray.count;
        }

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *cellid=@"CustomCell";
            CustomTableViewCell *cell=(CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];;

            if(cell==nil)
            {
                cell=[[CustomTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];

            }

           _entryDict= _jsonArray[indexPath.row];
            NSString *countryName = _entryDict[@"order"];

            NSMutableSet *seenCharacters = [NSMutableSet set];
            NSMutableString *resultf = [NSMutableString string];

              cell.nameLabel.text= countryName;


    if([cell.nameLabel.text isEqualToString:@"1"]){

         cell.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    }else{

           }

            return cell;
        }
```

Codes working success i need only real time refresh tableview rows . Im still working about 8-10 hours but i didn't resolve it.

Don't refresh each cell

**( My Error this : Showing red background on wrong rows when new rows added )**

```
if([cell.nameLabel.text isEqualToString:@"1"]){

   cell.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Thanks for help ! Thank you

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Do you just want to refresh the data in the entire table? A single row?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog entire table dude

Comment: There is a method for that... `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog yeah i added it everywhere but still nothing.

Comment: You need to add UITableViewDelegate where it says `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>` then set `tableView.delegate = self;` in viewDidLoad

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog Added them now refreshing table but don't refresh cells I have also   `cell.nameIcon.alpha = 1;`  for some cells ( With if codes )  don't refresh them.

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog look at codes i explain there dude added another codes

Comment: have any idea ? still nothing.

Comment: Well this is a new question from your original problem.  Looking at the code you posted, I don't see any problem.  The problem most likely lies in the code you did not post where you change the values in `_jsonArray`.  I would do an NSLog of the `_jsonArray` values for each row to make sure that the row number corresponds to the correct item in `_jsonArray`.  Try setting `cell.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` in the `else` section of your if statement

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog resolved give e question i will approve TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going from our discussion in the comments here are some options for solving the problem.

1) You need to add UITableView Delegate where is says `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>` then set `tableView.delegate = self;` in viewDidLoad

2) The new problem you faced most likely lies in the code you did not post where you change the values in `_jsonArray`. I would do an NSLog of the `_jsonArray` values for each row to make sure that the row number corresponds to the correct item in `_jsonArray`. Try setting `cell.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` in the else section of your if statement.